# Store value to variable from segmented control

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a segmented control for the user to select whether a driver is male/female.

How do i store the string "male" or "female" to a variable, dependant on what the user selects on the segmented control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your segmented control is set up correctly to respond to the control event **UIControlEventValueChanged**, you can access the index of the selected segment with **selectedSegmentIndex**

The default value is UISegmentedControlNoSegment (no segment selected) until the user touches a segment. Once they do, calling **selectedSegmentIndex:** will return a NSInteger. From there you can store the string male or female depending on the index.

Example:

```
NSString *gender = @"unknown";
NSInteger *selectedIndex = yoursegmentcontrol.selectedSegmentIndex;
if (selectedIndex == 0)
    gender = @"male";
else 
    gender = @"female";
```

Comment: what method would i be implementing this is?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the index that is selected and then you have to manually correspond the index to your value.